# How to get the real number of lines of TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I would like to know how I can get the number of lines of `TextView`.
I mean, I know they have this following code:

```
textview.setText(“Some text”);
textview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int lineCount = textview.getLineCount();
        logw("Test", "Number of line :" + lineCount);
    }
});
```

Here you can find my XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:text="Procedente igitur mox tempore cum adventicium nihil inveniretur, relicta ora maritima in Lycaoniam adnexam Isauriae se contulerunt ibique densis intersaepientes itinera pr"/>
```

But the problem is :

In my XML, I put a `setMaxLine = 3`
so Inside the method run, its always return 3 lines instead of 4 - 5 or more.

I don't know if it is clear.

Comment: Have you tried `textView.getLayout().getLineCount()`?

Comment: maxLines is used to limit the height of textview to the said lines.

Comment: @azizbekian yes i already try textView.getLayout().getLineCount()

Comment: @VivekMishra I know, but I used maxline to hide the rest of the line and put a Show more button, then when I click on this button, I set the new value: setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE); but only if (lineCount > 2 && lineCount != 3) but like I as said before, I put the maxLines to 3. So its always return me 3

Comment: don't set maxLines via xml. If you want to change try doing it with java

Comment: @VivekMishra same result

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
textview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    textview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    textView.getLayout().getLineCount()            
    }
            });
```

Comment: I can't use removeOnGlobalLayoutListener because I am on API 15

Comment: This worked but can you explain why do you remove the listener?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Kotlin suspend extension function that returns only if the `getLayout()` is not null; i.e., whenever the `TextView` has been laid out successfully.

```
suspend fun TextView.countLines() = withContext(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).coroutineContext) {
    var tvLayout = layout
    launch {
        while (tvLayout == null)
            tvLayout = layout
    }.join()
    tvLayout.lineCount
}
```

Usage:

```
CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
    val textView: TextView = ...
    val nLines = textView.countLines()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set `addTextChangedListener` on the textview as follows :

```
textview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // perform your process
                    Log.e("line count", String.valueOf(textview.getLineCount())); 
                }
            });
```